# In Html What is the difference between the "id" and "name" of an element?

Tags: script, html

I would have posted this to StackOverflow but I'm currently unable to post questions there so I was wondering what is the difference between the ID section and the Name section on tags such as:

```
<input id="datepicker" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00">
```

and

```
<input name="CalendarField1" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00">
```

I was thinking it was to do with calling different tags in certain scripts like id being called by CSS and name being called by java or vice versa am I correct in thinking this or is there any other circumstances where you would use the name section instead of the id section or vice versa?

Comment: Why couldn't you post in stackoverflow?  That is something to be solved

Comment: its a ban due to too many negative posts I don't really understand the point of banning on there but that's whats happened :/

Comment: If you're banned from asking on one site, that doesn't mean you can ask questions on other sites where they're off topic. I see you're a fairly active member, so you should rather try and fix your existing posts on Stack Overflow (possibly ask for moderators to undelete deleted questions), edit them into better shape and possibly get them reopened. Continuing to post off topic questions on other sites however may get you quickly banned there as well.

Comment: why has this question been put on hold? it has a valid answer and I didn't think the question was off topic here scenes as there is a tag for it. Plus I've had other scripting questions that were supported here and I've tried my best to do what I can on SO but nothing seems to have any effect and when it does I get blocked again because my questions are considered "too newbee"

Comment: @slhck is there a reason this is on hold? it has an answer and there is a tag for HTML and coding so I don't see how it is off topic? :S

Comment: Hi Nathan. You may find that the questions under the HTML tag which are about its syntax or coding are all closed. Also, whether or not it has an answer doesn't have anything to do with the topicality. We make exceptions for scripting that a power user or administrator would use, e.g. Bash or Excel VBA, what have you, but HTML is exclusively a programming thing.

Comment: @slhck ah well would it not stop confusion if the html tag was removed?

Comment: There are legitimate uses for the tag as well, e.g. how to configure your editor to handle HTML files, etc. A thorough cleanup of the tag would be good, but for the time being I edited the tag description.

Comment: ahh right no problem I forgot about the tag description that would be more effective than just simply deleting it I'll answer my question on meta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name is used when sending data in a form submission. Different controls respond differently. For example, you may have several radio buttons with different ids, but the same name. When submitted, there is just the one value in the response - the radio button you selected.

Of course, there's more to it than that, but it will definitely get you thinking in the right direction.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html)

Comment: Ah so the Name section is only used in forms?

Comment: yes, you can also use same name for making an `array` in case of radio buttons.

Comment: Right I get it now thanks I was confusing myself with my own script so I need to quote the "ID" in my php scripts instead of the name right?

Comment: Especially, the id must be unique per document. It can be used for "internal" purposes such as `<label for="datepicker">` or in CSS selectors `#datepicker`; also elements can be directly addressed by id, but not by name in JavScript. So the name is really just what is put into the form response (such as a GET `form.php?CalenderField1=xy`).

Comment: OK. You're welcome. But remember one thing **Please don't post any question w/o doing some research or google.** this will lead to odwn vote for your question.